# What HTTP headers does the WSO2 AM Gateway pass to the origin API server?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

What HTTP headers does the WSO2 API Manager Gateway pass along on the proxied request to the origin API server for an OAuth-authenticated request?  I can't find any documentation on this, is it in the docs somewhere and if so what's the URL?

It must include at least the application name / client id and user name where applicable, right?

Is it possible to store additional attributes per registered application and to pass those along as additional headers in the proxied requests?  How?

thx,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass those information to the back-end service as a JWT. To do this, set

```
<EnableTokenGeneration>
```

to true in api-manager.xml. The JWT will be passed as a base64 encoded string in the header. You can also add new values to be passed to the back-end service by customizing the JWTGenerator class. Refer[1]

[1] - http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/12/customize-json-web-token-generation-with-wso2-api-manager-1.8.0/

Comment: Thanks!  And I found the [documentation page](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Passing+Enduser+Attributes+to+the+Backend+Using+JWT) on this.